# Google Sheets formula to track number of event occurrence in the last 4 weeks

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, count, match, array-formulas

At work we are tracking a certain event that is suposed to occur once a week for each of our customers. A sample of the sheet we use to track this can be seen here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/128JhxL1gv2vTF027zkjYDGp48MIQ5-q9F9B6bIltCfM/edit#gid=0

I'm trying to create an index that counts how many events occurred in the last 4 weeks for each customer (i.e cells that contain "OK") but I'd like it to be updated as  the weeks go by without me having to change the range in the formula every week. Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: the event we are tracking is related to the COVID context so we can't be sure for how many weeks we'll keep tracking it. There are 8 weeks in the sample, but we may add ore over time

Comment: Will there be just 8 weeks in total?

Comment: No, we may add more weeks with time and we can't be sure how many weeks there will be (this event is related to the COVID context, hence the uncertainty). I'll edit the question to make it more clear!

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet1!A2:A, IF(Sheet1!A2:A="",, 
 MMULT( N(IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(2, MATCH("WK"&MAX(IF(
 (LEFT(Sheet1!1:1, 2)="WK")*(Sheet1!2:2<>""), COLUMN(Sheet1!1:1), ))-3, 
       Sheet1!1:1, 0), 4)&":100")="OK", 0)), 
 TRANSPOSE(N(LEFT(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(1, MATCH("WK"&MAX(IF(
 (LEFT(Sheet1!1:1, 2)="WK")*(Sheet1!2:2<>""), COLUMN(Sheet1!1:1), ))-3, 
       Sheet1!1:1, 0), 4)&":1"), 2)="WK"))))})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expand the weeks it might be a good idea to do the counting in a second tab. In the tab 'JPV' I entered in cell B2

```
=Arrayformula({Sheet1!A2:A, if(len(Sheet1!A2:A), mmult(N(Sheet1!B2:100="OK"), transpose(N(left(Sheet1!B1:1, 2)="WK"))),)})
```

See if that could work for you ?

UPDATED

Assuming you only add new weeks (headers) when the data (from row 2 and further down) for those weeks will be added to the table, you could try

```
=Arrayformula({Sheet1!A2:A, if(len(Sheet1!A2:A), mmult(N(Sheet1!B2:100="OK"), transpose( (left(Sheet1!B1:1, 2)="WK") * (substitute(Sheet1!B1:1, "WK",)+0 > MAX(substitute(Sheet1!B1:1, "WK",)+0)-4))),)})
```

Comment: It's a start! But I was hoping I could make it count only the last 4 weeks.. so, in the Sample, it would count from week 2 to week 5 and then, in the following week, it would count from week 3 to week 6 and so on